# Check Template Settings

Tags: typography, templates

Since I am new to LaTeX, is it possible to help me check if the required settings quoted bellow have been setted correctly in the template also quoted bellow?

The required settings:

> The text should be in 12-point typeface, double-spaced, and
>   left-justified. The pages should be numbered.

The template as it is now:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{acta}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is abstract text: This simple document shows very basic features of
\LaTeX{}.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation}
    \alpha = \sqrt{ \beta }
\end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{myfigure}
    \caption{Simulation Results}
    \label{simulationfigure}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 12-point typeface use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

For doublespace use

```
\usepacakge{setspace}
\spacing{1.5}
```

Finally, for having the text left aligned instead of justified use

```
\raggedright
```

after `\begin{document}`